# Como definir uma coluna com tamanho ajustavél dentro do container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container" style="background: yellow;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">

              </div>
              <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essa é a melhor forma de definir uma largura customizável dentro do um container?

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
```

Comment: Usando as colunas você define a largura usando o grid do bootstrap. Se esta largura é boa para você use-a. Senão ajuste para o tamanho desejado. Você também pode definir uma largura fixa com width, mas é melhor usar as colunas pois são ajustáveis.

Comment: Lembrando que no `bootstrap` existem 12 colunas, logo você divide com `col-md-x` onde `x` é o tamanho baseado na divisão. O `col-md-offset` **arrasta** sua `div` para a direita conforme o numero consequente em `col-md-offset-x`

Comment: O bootstrap reparte em 12 divisões por porcentagem de tela. Através do `col-x` você diz quantas partes sua coluna deve ocupar. `col-lg-x`,
`col-md-x`,
`col-sm-x`, são especificações conforme tamanho de tela... `lg`>`md`>`sm` * x é o número de partes (das 12) que sua coluna deve ocupar.

Comment: Tudo depende do produto final que você deseja, é bem relativo.Se quer agradar todo tamanho de tela, eu sugiro usar apenas `class="col-8"` desse jeito vai funcionar para todos os tipos de telas, `xl`, `lg`, `md`, `sm`, `xm`. Do jeito que fez, está especificando tamanho apenas para monitores de médio porte. Depende da sua necessidade! Se o foco do site for esse, está corretíssimo, caso contrário, ai em cima esta minha sugestão! Das duas formas você está fazendo um site responsivo, o que é ótimo hoje em dia, já que muitas pessoas acessam os sites pelo celular, computador ou até televisões...